# Why doesn't my bit left shift?

Tags: c, embedded, microcontroller, 8051, keil

I'm using embedded C on Keil. I'm trying to program such that it stores a bit, bit shifts and then it stores it again and it repeats until all eight bits are stored.

However, when I debug (maybe debug wrongly), the value only shows "01 00 00 00 00 00 00...". When it stores logic'1' and then when it shift left, it shows "02 00 00 00 00 00 00...". When the loop repeats, it shows the same thing over and over again. What I expected was "01 01 01 01 01 01 01..." (Let's say all the input bits was '1').  How do I solve this problem?

```
#include <reg51.h>

sbit Tsignal = P1^2;
unsigned char xdata x[500];

for(u=0; u<8; u++)
{
     x[i] = x[i] << 1;
     x[i] = Tsignal;  //Store Tsignal in x
}
```

Ah, I have solved it already.

```
unsigned int u;
unsigned char p;
unsigned char xdata x[500];

for(u=0; u<8; u++)    //Bit Shift Loop
{
    x[i] = x[i] <<1;   //Left Bit Shift by 1
    p = Tsignal;       //Store Tsignal to Buffer p
    x[i] |= p;
} //End Bitshift loop
```

Comment: In standard C there is no direct support for bitarrays. Are you using something specific to Keil - could you include your definition of x?

Comment: Why are you immediately overwriting the value you created with `Tsignal`?

Comment: #include <reg51.h>

sbit Tsignal = P1^2;

unsigned char xdata x[500];

Comment: @xrainxfallx It is perfectly fine to post an answer to your own question. Just give others time to reply before you accept any of the answers as the correct answer, including your own one.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to do something like this:

```
for(u=0;u<8;u++)
{
  // Update Tsignal.
  //Tsignal = GetBitValue();

  // Store it to x.
  x = (x << 1) | (Tsignal & 0x1)
}
```

Comment: May I know what is your GetBitValue(); Function?

Comment: I think you want to OR it not AND it  x = (x << 1) | (Tsignal & 1)

Comment: GetBitValue() is pseudo-code. It represents a function that returns the bit value of, for instance, a general purpose digital input.